# Replace one app by another in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

Good afternoon. There is a project, it is published in appstore. A major update is planned - the project will be fully rewritten. Can I replace an existing application in the App Store with a new one to make it look like a normal update for the user? Can I release an update to a new application in the itunes connect replacing only Bundle Id? Thank you

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of submitting the app with the same bundle identifier for a given App Apple ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the standard procedure of updating an existing app. You might want check Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

There are only 3 important things:

- Bundle ID: Needs to be exactly the same as you can see in iTunes Connect
- Version Number: Need to be higher than last in iTunes Connect. Not talking about the "customer-facing" version number but the actual one you can see in the list of builds
- Build Number: Counter begins with every version.